# Can't pass object keys as local variables to a function

Tags: javascript, function, object, variables

- I'm trying to create a function which will declare variables with selected elements from an object looks like this

```
var el = {
    'btn1': '#btn',
    'time1': '#time',
    'audio': 'audio',
    'elem': '.elem'
}
```

- the function contains 2 arguments

  1. first argument is for the object
  2. second argument is a function who i want to pass the variables to him
- i want to pass declared variables as local varibles to the second arguments
- I used `new Function()` to get the keys as variable name then assign the values to them
- i tried `apply()`, `bind()` to pass the vatiables to the function

> The Problem is

- `apply()`, `bind()` set the variables to the window object to make them global variables and i want them a local variables to this function
- **Here's my function**

```
function selectElements(obj, fn) {
  if (typeof fn === 'function') {
    for(var i in obj) {
        obj[i] = obj[i].replace(/^\#/, function(selectedElem) {
            selectedElem = obj[i].replace(/^\#/, '');
            new Function('return '+ fn+'.bind('+i+' = document.getElementById("'+selectedElem+'"))')()
        }).replace(/^\./, function(selectedElem) {
            selectedElem = obj[i].replace(/^\./, '');
            new Function('return '+ fn+'.bind('+i+' = document.getElementsByClassName("'+selectedElem+'"))')()
        }).replace(/^\w+/, function(selectedElem) {
            if (!selectedElem.startsWith('undefined')) {
                new Function('return '+ fn +'.bind('+i+' = document.getElementsByTagName("'+selectedElem+'"))')()
            }
        })
    }
  }
}
```

- another simple example if i done the following also will set x to the window object

```
function selectElements(obj, fn) {
  fn.bind(x = 123)
}
```

- all i want is to pass the keys as variables with selected element to the `fn` not to the window object

> The Complete Code

```js
var el = {
  'btn1': '#btn',
  'time1': '#time',
  'audio': 'audio',
  'elem': '.elem'
}

function selectElements(obj, fn) {
  var sel;
  if (typeof fn === 'function') {
    for (var i in obj) {
      obj[i] = obj[i].replace(/^\#/, function(selectedElem) {
        selectedElem = obj[i].replace(/^\#/, '');
        sel = ' = document.getElementById("' + selectedElem + '")'
        new Function('return ' + fn + '.bind(' + i + sel + ')')()
      }).replace(/^\./, function(selectedElem) {
        selectedElem = obj[i].replace(/^\./, '');
        sel = ' = document.getElementsByClassName("' + selectedElem + '")'
        new Function('return ' + fn + '.bind(' + i + sel + ')')()
      }).replace(/^\w+/, function(selectedElem) {
        if (!selectedElem.startsWith('undefined')) {
          sel = ' = document.getElementsByTagName("' + selectedElem + '")'
          new Function('return ' + fn + '.bind(' + i + sel + ')')()
        }
      })
    }
    fn()
  }
}
selectElements(el, function() {
  console.log(window)
  console.log(btn1, time1, audio, elem)
})
```

```html
<div id="time"></div>
<audio controls src="audio.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
<button id="btn">play</button>
<div class="elem">000</div>
```

Comment: what about `this.btn1` will it work for you?

Comment: I'm looking for use them directly without `this` keyword but also when using `this` inside the function it's return the `window` object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the only way you can do it is within the function itself and via the evil `eval()`...

```js
var el = {
  'btn1': '#btn',
  'time1': '#time',
  'audio': 'audio',
  'elem': '.elem'
}

function selectElements(obj, fn) {
  if (typeof fn === 'function') {
    const that = {};
    for (let i in obj)
      that[i] = document["querySelector" + (obj[i][0] == "#" ? "" : "All")](obj[i]);

    return fn.bind(that)();
  }
}
selectElements(el, function() {
  for(let i in this)
  {
    let t = this[i];
    eval("var " + i + "=t");
  }
  console.log("global", window.btn1, window.time1, window.audio, window.elem);
  console.log("local", btn1, time1, audio, elem)
  console.log("this", this.btn1, this.time1, this.audio, this.elem)
})
```

```html
<div id="time"></div>
<audio controls src="audio.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
<button id="btn">play</button>
<div class="elem">000</div>
```

Or via very "hacky" way of recreating the callback function adding argument variables to it, but it has scope issues:

```js
var el = {
  'btn1': '#btn',
  'time1': '#time',
  'audio': 'audio',
  'elem': '.elem'
}

function selectElements(obj, fn) {
  if (typeof fn === 'function') {
    const that = {};
    for (let i in obj)
      that[i] = document["querySelector" + (obj[i][0] == "#" ? "" : "All")](obj[i]);

    let f = fn.toString();
    return new Function(...Object.keys(that), f.slice(f.indexOf("{") + 1, f.lastIndexOf("}"))).apply(null, Object.values(that));
  }
}

selectElements(el, function() {
  console.log("global", window.btn1, window.time1, window.audio, window.elem);
  console.log("local", btn1, time1, audio, elem)
  console.log("this", this.btn1, this.time1, this.audio, this.elem)
})


//this doesn't work, because callback function will be recreated in different scope
for(let i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
  selectElements(el, function()
  {
    console.log(i);
    console.log(btn1);
  });
}
```

```html
<div id="time"></div>
<audio controls src="audio.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
<button id="btn">play</button>
<div class="elem">000</div>
```

I would not recommend any of these methods though...

Comment: Thank you that's cool i recreated the function in nother way then called him by `new Function()` but why you don't recommend usage of those i think `new Function()` is a safe way it's creating a function and execute the string

Comment: Simply because the new function will be in different scope than the original. I've added an example in the answer showing the issue. Also it's not very universal, it doesn't work with one-line arrow functions: `selectElements(el, e => console.log(btn1));`